# How to get the address of node->next pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I was writing code on Doubly Linked List for the following function

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

/* Given a node as next_node, insert a new node before the given node */
void insertBefore(struct node** next_node, int new_data)
```

I called the insertBefore() from the main function:

```
 insertBefore(&head, 2);  // it works fine
```

But i can't do the same fore head->next, because next pointer is just node* Not node**

```
insertBefore(head->(&next), 2);  // it doesn't works
```

How can i solve the problem.please help.Thanks

Comment: `&(head->next)`

Comment: Or `&head->next`.

Comment: Or if you are not sure:
struct node *next = head->next;
insertBefore(&next, 2);

Comment: [Off Topic] `struct node *next;` is a C-ism.  In C++ you do not need to qualify a struct with `struct`

Comment: _"How can i solve the problem."_ Use the language how it's meant to be used, i.e. use `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your function works, `&(head->next)` is what you need.

```
insertBefore(&(head->next), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`head` is a pointer in case of `insertBefore(&head, 2);`

`next` is also a pointer and a member of `struct node`.

So, if you want to access `next` via `head` (i.e pointer to some node) then,

syntax would be `head->next`. Now you can get address of `next` by `&(head->next)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to take a reference to the node pointer.

```
void insertBefore(node*& next_node, int new_data);
...
insertBefore(head->next, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems illogical to dereference a pointer than reference its address...

`&(head->next)` will work but it works because you dereference the pointer (grab the value that the pointer points to) than grab the address of that pointer again using `&`.

`->` is the same as `.(*next)`.  The arrow is just the easiest way to get what the pointer points to. If you want the value of the pointer itself all you have to do is `head.next`.